# Grails spring security authentication provider and custom filter

Tags: java, spring, grails, groovy, spring-security

I'm new to the grails language and am using grails 2.5.6 with spring-security-core 2.0.0 plugin at work.

I've defined my provider as this in the `config.groovy` file:

```
grails.plugin.springsecurity.providerNames = [
    'myCustomAuthenticationProvider',
    'anonymousAuthenticationProvider',
    'rememberMeAuthenticationProvider'
]
```

and my filter as:

```
grails.plugin.springsecurity.filterChain.filterNames = [
    'securityContextPersistenceFilter',
    'myCustomFilter',
    'exceptionTranslationFilter', 
    'anonymousAuthenticationFilter',
    'filterInvocationInterceptor'
]
```

My `resources.groovy` file:

```
myCustomAuthenticationProvider(MyCustomAuthenticationProvider)
myCustomFilter(myCustomFilter)
```

Both my filter and provider are java classes provided by a jar. The filter extends `OncePerRequestFilter` and has the `AuthenticationManager` and `AuthenticationEntryPoint` injected. My provider implements `AuthenticationProvider`

The problem is when I put a debug point in my filter to see the `AuthenticationManager` and see the `AuthenticationProviders that are in it's list, I don't see my custom provider at all. I still see the default spring-security-core plugin providers.

<del>I also don't understand why my custom filter gets initiated even if I remove it from the list of filters. It seems like just defining it in the `resources.groovy` file is enough for it to get initiated.</del>

Just realized that the reason it gets initiated is because on startup it is being added to the spring container.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Figured it out. I ended up not defining the filterNames and in my `resources.groovy` file I have this:

```
authenticationProcessingFilter(MyCustomFilter) {
    ...args
}
```

And the issue with my provider on construction getting the providers doesn't matter. Turns out spring security core doesn't change it until after that.